# How to convert this line of code from Python to Julia?

Tags: python, list, function, julia, assign

In brief, I have the code below in Python

```
[n, m] = f()
```

and I want to convert it to Julia, which will not be more than one line (I hope).

Here is an example in Python:

```
from numpy import *

x = [0,1,2]
y = [3,4,5]
x = array(x)
y = array(y)

def f():
    z = concatenate((x, y))
    a = z*2
    b = z*3
    return [a, b]

def g():
    [n,m] = f()
    n = n/2
    m = m/3
    return [n, m]

print(g())
```

This is how I wanted it to be in Julia, but did not work:

```
x = [0,1,2]
y = [3,4,5]

function f()
    z = vcat(x, y)
    a = z*2
    b = z*3
    return [a, b]
end

function g()
    [n, m] = f()
    n = n/2
    m = m/3
    return [n, m]
end

print(g())
```

Here is how I made it work, but I do not want codes like this:

```
x = [0,1,2]
y = [3,4,5]

function f()
    z = vcat(x, y)
    a = z*2
    b = z*3
    global c = [a, b]
    return c
end

function g()
    n = c[1]
    m = c[2]
    n = n/2
    m = m/3
    return [n, m]
end

f()
print(g())
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that `[n, m] = f()` is not idiomatic of python either. Typically you should just write `n, m = f()`, just like in julia.

Comment: Don't use global variables. They are bad. Pass `x` and `y` as input arguments to the functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just drop square brackets like this:

```
x = [0,1,2]
y = [3,4,5]

function f()
    z = vcat(x, y)
    a = z*2
    b = z*3
    return a, b # here it is not needed, but typically in such cases it is dropped to return a tuple
end

function g()
    n, m = f() # here it is needed
    n = n/2
    m = m/3
    return n, m # here it is not needed, but typically in such cases it is dropped to return a tuple
end

print(g())
```

The reason why it is typically better to return a `Tuple` rather than a vector is that `Tuple` does not perform auto promotion of values (+ it is non-allocating):

```
julia> (1, 2.0) # here 1 stays an integer
(1, 2.0)

julia> [1, 2.0] # here 1 got implicitly converted to 1.0
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 2.0
```

Of course if you want such implicit behavior use a vector.